# MultiScrolling UIColectionView inside UIScrollView

Tags: swift, xcode, scroll, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a Profile View Controller, and It's parent view is a `scrollView`. But inside it, there is a `collectionView` for Recipes.

Sample Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziRC7.png

I want to manage Scrolling between `scrollView` and `collectionView`. So in my `scrollViewDidScroll` function, I wrote this code, but it doesn't work.

```
class userProfileView: UIViewController ,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var recipesCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var main_scrollview: UIScrollView!

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if (recipesCollectionView.contentOffset.y <= 0 && main_scrollview.contentOffset.y < (main_scrollview.contentSize.height - main_scrollview.frame.size.height))  {

            main_scrollview.isScrollEnabled = true
            recipesCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }

    else if (main_scrollview.contentOffset.y >= (main_scrollview.contentSize.height - main_scrollview.frame.size.height)) {

        main_scrollview.isScrollEnabled = false
        recipesCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = true


    }

 }

}
```

What is the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Handling nested scroll is always a pain; you should consider to use a single collection view

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio unfortunately I can't use a single Collection. Isn't there any way to handle it by code?

Answer (score 0):

Nested scrolling views can be a difficult to manage. You have to write logic for things like velocity, and where the scroll started from.

You could use a tableview with a cell that has a collection view inside.This will handle the problems you are having as the scrolling logic is handled for you.

As a general rule, I wouldn't use custom scroll views unless you have a very good reason. TableViews and CollectionViews are powerful enough for most common layouts and scenarios.